# Jenkins Pipeline "Unexpected token"

Tags: jenkins-groovy

I've copied a old class into my existing project and altered it for the new requirements.

Pipeline Groovy points to the first letter of my constructor and tells me:

```
"workflowScript: nnn: Unexpected token: XXX @ line nnn, column n. "
```

What has happened?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jap, I've renamed the class. Forgot to rename the constructor so. hmpf...
And I've received this absolutely not useful error message. Hope this helps someone!